# ZFS - use pure ACLs to force group write permissions to be inherited

Tags: solaris, zfs, access-control-list

I am migrating a directory structure from a UFS filesystem to ZFS. In the old location I had POSIX ACLs set to force all new files/directories within the structure to be created with group write permissions -

```
group::rwx
default:group::rwx
```

On the new ZFS filesystem I have attempted to replicate this using NFSv4 ACLs with the "file_inherit/dir_inherit" flags set, but find that these are stripped out (or in the case of directories, replaced by an ACE with "inherit_only" set), so other users in the group **don't** have write permissions in the new directory. For example:

```
$ chmod A+group@:rwxp:fd:allow .
$ ls -Vd .
drwxrws---+  6 user1    grp1         13 Nov  8 12:55 .
            group@:rwxp----------:fd----:allow
            owner@:--------------:------:deny
            owner@:rwxp---A-W-Co-:------:allow
            group@:--------------:------:deny
            group@:rwxp----------:------:allow
         everyone@:rwxp---A-W-Co-:------:deny
         everyone@:------a-R-c--s:------:allow
$ mkdir test
$ ls -Vd test
drwxr-sr-x+  2 user1    grp1          2 Dec  1 14:24 test
            group@:rwxp----------:fdi---:allow
            group@:--------------:------:allow
            owner@:--------------:------:deny
            owner@:rwxp---A-W-Co-:------:allow
            group@:-w-p----------:------:deny
            group@:r-x-----------:------:allow
         everyone@:-w-p---A-W-Co-:------:deny
         everyone@:r-x---a-R-c--s:------:allow
$ touch afile
$ ls -V afile
-rw-r--r--+  1 user1    grp1          0 Dec  1 14:40 afile
            group@:--------------:------:allow
            owner@:--x-----------:------:deny
            owner@:rw-p---A-W-Co-:------:allow
            group@:-wxp----------:------:deny
            group@:r-------------:------:allow
         everyone@:-wxp---A-W-Co-:------:deny
         everyone@:r-----a-R-c--s:------:allow
```

I can fix this by setting umask to 002 but I'd like to know if there's a pure ACL way (as the versions of FTP and SSH currently installed don't allow umask to be set on a per-user basis).

Answer (score 4):

I use something like below for my passwordless, NAS storage.  I'm not well versed on all the fine-grained permissions so it's probably overkill on owner/group perms and underkill on everyone, but here it is:

```
setfacl -m owner@:full_set:fd:allow /zfs/raid1/storage
setfacl -m group@:full_set:fd:allow /zfs/raid1/storage
setfacl -m everyone@:rx:fd:allow /zfs/raid1/storage
```

It's on FreeBSD, so ZFS's NFSv4 ACLs are built into setfacl.  I think they can also be in nfs4_setfacl and chmod on some OSes.  I'm very new to ACLs and even newer to FreeBSD, as well, so this all may make sysadmins cry.  It also acts as `chmod 2774` and sets new files'/directories' groups to the dataset's group.

Edit to clarify a bit: `/zfs/raid1` is the actual ZFS mount, `storage` is a dataset within it.